# Working with two jquery document.ready functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two document.ready functions as shown below:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#slider1').s3Slider({
            timeOut: 3000 
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".modalbox").fancybox();
     $("#contact").submit(function() {
    return false;
});
```

The first is a banner jquery that is supposed to rotate forever. The second is a contact form modal box that appears on the user's click. Is it possible for the two to coexist?

Comment: Why don't you just try it by yourself ?

Comment: Why don't you put both things inside a single document.ready?

Comment: it would work indeed, but the best approach is to wrap them in a single document.ready()

Comment: By the way, you are not closing well second `document.ready`. You are just closing the `submit` event.

Comment: Please explain what problem you're encountering. SO is not the correct venue for hypotheticals.

Comment: @maverickosama92 It's definitely not best approach. It depends on the context. For example if you use few libraries with `.ready()` then you won't be modifying them now will you?

Answer (score 0):

Of course. You only add more handlers to `ready` event and **all** of them will fire once the `ready` event fires.

Answer (score 0):

Totally possible. In your example it is just an overhead but you can perfectly have two subscribers to an event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(init);
function init(){
    banner();
    contactForm();
}
function banner(){ 
    $('#slider1').s3Slider({timeOut: 3000});
}
function contactForm(){
    $(".modalbox").fancybox();
    $("#contact").submit(...);
}
```